# Creating a leash line on Google Maps that ties a marker to a specific location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use a leash line to tie a location point on Google Maps to a marker that can be moved to any arbitrary place on the map.  Similar to what Google Maps does when multiple markers are selected or in near proximity except I would like to permanently move the marker and leave it in the off-set position with the leash line attached??

Any ideas on how to do this in Google Maps API 3.

Comment: Please provide some research details. What have you tried to solve your problem

Comment: Look at the Overlapping Marker Spiderfier discussed in this question: [Google Maps Spiderfying Markers & Adding Listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197724/google-maps-spiderfying-markers-adding-listeners)